# How to run tests in specific order - Playwright YAML file

Tags: angular, typescript, azure, pipeline

I got stuck when i'm creating a azure pipeline for my playwright test. I want the tests to run in a specific order.

This is how my YAML file looks right now, but now it just run all testes in not the right order.

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '18'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: npm ci
  displayName: 'npm ci'

- script: npx playwright install --with-deps
  displayName: 'Install Playwright browsers'

- script: npx playwright test
  displayName: 'Run Playwright tests'

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish test results'
  inputs:
    searchFolder: 'test-results'
    testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
    testResultsFiles: 'e2e-junit-results.xml'
    mergeTestResults: true
    failTaskOnFailedTests: true
    testRunTitle: 'My End-To-End Tests'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: playwright-report
    artifact: playwright-report
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

Here is my structure. For example I want to run createTraveler.spec.ts first, than createSingleTrip.spec.ts
[Structure File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKTGW.png)

I have tried writing

```
- script: |
    npx jest ./Digor.Web/playwright-tests/createTraveler.spec.ts
  displayName: 'Run createTraveler.spec.ts'

- script: |
    npx jest ./Digor.Web/playwright-tests/createSingleTrip.spec.ts
  displayName: 'Run createSingleTrip.spec.ts'
```

but does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I cloned [**this**](https://github.com/VinayKumarBM/playwright-sample-project/tree/master) repository and tried running the test file in a specific order.

***My Azure cloned repository:-***

[image]

***I tried running CreateAccountTest.spec.ts before ContactUsTest.spec.ts and it ran successfully with the code below:-***

**My Yaml code:-**

```yaml
trigger:
  - main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '18'
    displayName: 'Install Node.js'

  - script: npm ci
    displayName: 'npm ci'

  - script: npx playwright install --with-deps
    displayName: 'Install Playwright browsers'

  
  - script: npx playwright test src/tests/files/CreateAccountTest.spec.ts
    displayName: 'Run CreateAccountTest.spec.ts'

 
  - script: npx playwright show-report test-results/results
    displayName: 'Show test report'
    
  
  - script: npx playwright test src/tests/files/ContactUsTest.spec.ts
    displayName: 'Run ContactUsTest.spec.ts'

  
  - script: npx playwright show-report test-results/results
    displayName: 'Show test report'
```

[image]

You can refer this [**link**](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-cli) to run the npx playwright command in different order by sepcifying the filter.

- Run npx command with file name my-spec and my-spec-2

```
    npx playwright test my-spec my-spec-2
```

- Run test of specific project

```
   npx playwright test  --project=chromium
```